# Why does a string break into letters when adding it as list replacement, if the index range does not get the complete list of replacement values?

Tags: python

So I created this list:

```
desk = ['mouse', 'matchbox', 'laptop', 'water']
```

When replacing the first the two values of the list with new strings, but for a test case, not providing the second replacement string value, python breaks the first replacement value into individual letters in the list. For example:

```
desk[0:2] = 'mouse'

desk : ['m', 'o', 'u', 's', 'e', 'laptop', 'water']
```

I'm aware that this might not ever be of use, but I just wanted to be clear on the logic behind this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A list is a sequence of some objects. A string is a sequence of characters. Here you replace a part of the list sequence by another sequence (the string).

Answer (score 0):

A slice assignment of the form

```
dest[start:end] = source
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
# remove old contents of the slice
for _ in range(start, end):
    dest.pop(start)
# insert replacement in its place
for el in source:
    dest.insert(start, el)
```

When `source` is a string, `for el in source:` means to iterate over the characters, so the string is split up.

If you want to make the string a single element, wrap it in a list.

```
desk[0:2] = ['mouse']
```